# Header names keep retaining double-quote text qualifier when importing flatfile into SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql-server

Trying to import a TSV file into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3156.0 and having problem where when specifying the text qualifier for the data, when looking at the row preview, I can see that the program thinks the name of the columns are `"<column_name>"` (quotes included). The actual column data appears to be formatted correctly, just not the column names. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import wizard also includes a check box for specifying that the import file also contains header names
[image]
Unchecking and rechecking this box after entering the text qualifier character seems to fix the problem (perhaps "refreshes" the column header data?).